# Keyboards, mice, touchpads work on Wayland and don't work on Xorg in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, xorg, touchpad

My keyboards, mice and touchpads (following “KMT”):
Work in Windows
Work on both Xorg and Wayland in Ubuntu 20.04
Work on Wayland in Ubuntu 22.04
Don't work on Xorg in Ubuntu 22.04.

My KMT works in Wayland DEs like Ubuntu Default, Weston, etc. But they don't work in Xorg DEs like Ubuntu on Xorg, Xfce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself:
I just run `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` and try to get into Xorg again, now the keyboards and mice can be used.